# Shock induced illuminated material

Tags: materials, reference-request, photochemistry

Any suggestions for a shock induced material that would illuminate and be capable of being visible for a minimum of three seconds? Non-toxic and minimal heat production would be optimal.

Comment: You're asking about [mechanoluminescent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanoluminescence) material?

Comment: And what kind of money would you expect to earn from this stuff? ;-)